# Python list appending in a loop not working as intended

Tags: python, list, loops, return, append

A have a case where i receive a integer value(cents) and need to find all the change possibilities with quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies, and return a set of all the ways.
I've made some code that works partially.

```
QUARTER = 25
DIME = 10
NICKEL = 5
PENNIE = 1

def makeChange(value):
    way_list = []
    way = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    for q_q in range((value // QUARTER) + 1):
        way[0] = q_q
        value_after_Q = value - (q_q * QUARTER)

        for d_q in range((value_after_Q // DIME) + 1):
            way[1] = d_q
            value_after_D = value_after_Q - (d_q * DIME)

            for n_q in range((value_after_D // NICKEL) + 1):
                way[2] = n_q
                value_after_N = value_after_D - (n_q * NICKEL)
                p_q = value_after_N // PENNIE
                way[3] = p_q
                print(way)    # this print shows my results one by one
                way_list.append(way)  # but this append only appends the last possible result, multiple times
                # makes a set:
                way_list = [
                    _way
                    for ind, _way in enumerate(way_list)
                    if _way not in way_list[:ind]
                ]
    return way_list

print(makeChange(25))
```

The print on the last loop prints me:

```
[0, 0, 0, 25]
[0, 0, 1, 20]
[0, 0, 2, 15]
[0, 0, 3, 10]
[0, 0, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 5, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 15]
[0, 1, 1, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 5]
[0, 1, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 5]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Which is not wrong, but i need it inside a set.
When i try to append the "way" list to the propper "way_list", it only appends the [1, 0, 0, 0], multiple times.

Comment: It's because you're adding the variable `way` into the list. So every time you update the variable `way` you update all instances of it in the list too. To check this I did `print(way_list)` after the append

Comment: Ok, you nailed it. Just added a copy() after the way in append and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by `but i need it inside a set`?

Comment: i cant have any duplicates, so a put everthing inside a list and delete the dups.